# python3.5 NP indexing out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy

posted a two part question earlier, and only got the first part answered, but the second part is still confusing me

so I was wondering what is going on here

```
y = np.array([]*100)
y[0:50] = 1
y[50:100] = -1

print(y[34])
```

in my mind, I created an np array of 1D, first 50 values take 1 and the other fifty values take -1, i know Im on python 3.5 so ive got to print actual indexes instead of the whole thing, which would return a memory object and location, but why does it give this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saminahbab/Documents/Programming /untitled/new_traying.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(y[34])
IndexError: index 34 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

EDIT

fixed with initializing it with 100 0's instead and then changing values 
can someone tell me why the original approach did not work?

Comment: Print `y` or examine `y.shape`. You'll see it's empty (i.e. length 0, because `[]*100` is just `[]`).

Comment: ah I see thank you thank you makes sense now

Comment: It's better to create an array of length 100 by using `y = np.empty(100)` or `y = np.zeros(100)`. You can specify the dtype too (integer, floating, complex, ...).

Answer (score 0):

The first line creates an array of size 0. 
You can create an array of 100 elements using this :

y = numpy.zeros(shape=(100,1))